# getting value first offset name after click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can get value `2011` in `input:name` with jquery?

```
<input type="text" name="hi[2011][]">
```

**[Example:](http://jsfiddle.net/QRkjs/)**

```
<button>Click me</button>
<input type="text" name="hi[2011][]">


$('button').click(function() {
    var f_offset = $('input').prop('name');
    alert(f_offset);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var f_offset = $('input').prop('name');
    alert(f_offset.match(/\d+/)[0]);
})
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nDthf/)

Comment: by 8 seconds... and you don't need g

Comment: @Joseph, thanks I think my mind puts that g in there without thinking half the time.

Comment: ok, how can add value '2012' in first offset name after click? Example: http://jsfiddle.net/QRkjs/1/

Comment: `if (name.match(/\d+/)[0] == "2011")` => Always value is not `2011`. It is an example. !?